# Uploading PNG File results in Status 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: jersey, jersey-client

I am stumped here. I am developing a test to upload a PNG file to a REST service and continue to get 406 Not Acceptable as a response.

I am using jersey-bundle 1.19.3

Here is the Request:

```
Apr 12, 2017 12:20:17 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://localhost:7001/api/1/payments/XT491926022464/attachments
1 > Accept: application/xml
1 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1492014017228
1 > Api-Key: 2222
1 > Authorization: Bearer 1152921504606857464
-----------------------------1492014017228
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requestId"

1234
-----------------------------1492014017228
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

BankCustomerAttachmentTestImage.PNG
-----------------------------1492014017228
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

TEST
-----------------------------1492014017228
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="junit8251833935221639216.tmp";   name="file"

...
```

Here is the RESPONSE:

```
Apr 12, 2017 12:20:17 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 406
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 16:20:17 GMT
1 < Content-Length: 14
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
1 < Connection: close
1 < X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
1 < 
Not Acceptable
```

And here is the code...What an I doing wrong?

```
    DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client restClient = Client.create(config);
    restClient.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

    WebResource restWebResource = restClient.resource("http://...");
    WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder = restWebResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

webResourceBuilder.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
webResourceBuilder.header(RESTActor.HEADER_API_KEY, "1234");
webResourceBuilder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + "1152921504606857464");

FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", fileObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

    fileDataBodyPart.setContentDisposition(
    FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName(fileObject.getName()).build());

    FormDataMultiPart multiPartForm = new FormDataMultiPart();
    multiPartForm.field("requestId", "1234");
    multiPartForm.field("file", "BankCustomerAttachmentTestImage.PNG");
    multiPartForm.field("description", "TEST");

    multiPartForm.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);
    multiPartForm.setMediaType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

    final String boundary = "---------------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    ClientResponse currentRestClientResponse =
 webResourceBuilder.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA + "; boundary=" + boundary).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPartForm);
```

Comment: Is the server supposed to return XML?

Answer (score 2):

In your request you indicate that the client accepts only application/xml content-type:

```
1 > Accept: application/xml
```

But the server is not capable to return this content type, that's what 406 Not Acceptable error means.
Your client must accept the content-type returning by the server, which is:

```
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

To do so, change the MediaType in the following line to MediaType.TEXT_HTML:

```
    WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder = restWebResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
```

Then check the real server response. It may turn out that there is another issue on the server side, e.g. it responses with HTTP 500 status code, and once you resolve it, you will need to adjust the accepted media type to some specific.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work using APPLICATION_JSON for return type

Comment: The following worked:

WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder = restWebResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); Using

WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder = restWebResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML); gets 406

Comment: Perfect, glad you found solution